# Create a .sql file in php

Tags: php, sql

I have used the bellow code for get the wp-option value.

```
function option_value_change () {
  global $wpdb;
  $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *
  FROM `wp_options`");
    foreach ($myrows as $rows){
      $option = get_option($rows->option_name);
            $optin_id = $rows->option_id;
            $option_name = $rows->option_name;
            $option_value = $row->option_value;
            $option_load = $row->option_autoload;
            echo $option_value;
    }
}
```

now i want to create a .sql file using those above values. How can i create a .sql file using those values.

Comment: Simply i want to create another sql file using those data. So ,i have to know how to create sql file using php.

Comment: I don't understand lyk what you exactly need. a sql file with what inside it.. insert commands or select commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to generate the create table and insert statements manually. There is a good article here that has a backup script written in PHP.

http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php