# how to generate sql file to insert input from php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a form that after i click submit,it will generate .sql file to insert the value to MySQL database. so I can transfer the value to other server  real time.

How to generate SQL file that contain a script to insert value from input form?

we have a lot of outlet, usually we use web app from browser to input database, but there is a problem when the connection is down, so we tried to make the web app running from outlet server and transfer all the input to HO ftp server.

I already create batch file to transfer the file to ftp and will use cronjob to run it automatically, what left is I want to generate SQL file to insert the input data, so I can import the SQL to HO database from ftp server.

Here is the example:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br> E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

It will show name, email, text box and submit button. I want to generate SQL file that insert name and email input when I click submit button. not generate SQL file from MySQL.

Comment: You would normally use a computer for that. But to be serious, why a SQL file? Why not connect to the databases in _real_ real time and INSERT the data? I also found [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105036/util-method-for-generating-an-insert-sql-dynamically)

Comment: yes, of course it will be insert to local database, but I also want to send the input to ftp server. we have a lot of outlet and we want to create ftp server in HO, so all outlet can send the input realtime to ftp server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a .sql file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828056/create-a-sql-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I think this is a bad solution for security reason. FTP is a breakable protocol, but anyway: you can do this by calling the PHP method:

`file_put_contents();`

So after compose the SQL string to store into the file, you can do something like this:

```
$dir = 'folderPATH';
$dataToStore = "INSERT INTO table_name (name, email, ...) VALUES ('$name', '$email');"
file_put_contents($dir, $dataToStore);
```

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work, but now i know that i can start working from this. I know it's not a good solution, but at least it can work first and then start to upgrade the system.thanks a lot.